# List View in android not visible

Tags: android

I'm facing problem with list view, I wrote following code for list view but when i run that code, list view not visible, the code is as follows:

```
l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] a1=new String[]{"abc", "bcd","cde","def"};
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, a1);
        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: l1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapteradapter);

Comment: l1.setAdapter(adapter); as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are missing to set Adapter to listview. Update your code to below code.

```
    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            String[] a1=new String[]{"abc", "bcd","cde","def"};
            ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, a1);
            l1.setAdapter(adapter);
            l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

set listadapter first.

l1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapteradapter);

Answer (score 0):

Is your layout properly written? Means ListView visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your listview doesn't get visible because you have not set the data in your listview using adapter.

set the adapter in your listview as below:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, a1);
   l1.setAdapter(adapter);
```